# Check if values in a form have been changed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Good Afternoon!

I have a situation and I don't know how solve it!

I'm using primefaces and I have a fieldSet with several fields and a commandButton called "Save" disabled inside it. So I need to enable the commandButton if any value of any field were modified. I know that there's the "onChange" event, but I have many fields, I would like to know if there's a way to check the whole form, I mean all fields at once, not field by field!

I'm using Primefaces 5.1

PS: If I wrote something wrong please sorry, just ask me and I will try to put it in other words!

Thank you all in advance